# How to read a data sent to my Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, transactions, dapps, calldata

How can I read/ get a data that has ben sent to my smart contract ?

I tested sendTransaction({data: xyz }) and when I tried to get this data from the Smart Contract using msg.data I got NULL this means the data wasn't sent to the SC , any help ? a need the line code of the transaction with a data

Comment: please give example code of both your smart contract and your interfacing method (geth?) to try this. otherwise it is hard to help out specifically.

Comment: token.addAssets.sendTransaction(1,{from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether'), data: web3.toHex("0x228aef67c65077f864d9f5e00697578627f3b331")});
this is my transaction

Comment: this is my smart contract function

Comment: function addAssets(int amount) returns (bytes)
    {ad=msg.data;
        if (msg.sender == 0xd1b4b395a0f9deff0275c3cca2eeb9539af365e2)
        balanceOf[msg.sender]=balanceOf[msg.sender]+amount;
        else throw;
        return ad;
    }

Answer (score 5):

Assume you have a solidity function inside your smart contract which accepts data in the form of e.g. an integer called xyz:

`function takeData(int xyz)`

Now in e.g. geth you can create an instance of that smart contract and call the function by:

`contractInstance.takeData.sendTransaction(12345, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]})`

You can find a complete walk-through example which I created for our teaching efforts at [Validity Labs](http://validitylabs.org) on my github: https://github.com/SCBuergel/timeLock-smartContract